# PHP: Check if objects contain a string from array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have been searching on Google and this platform to find an answer but I am unable to make it work. So here is my situation:

What I want:

To check for each object if it contains a string which is defined in an array and only output objects which pass this condition.

What I got:

```
$mail_body = "<table>.....</table>";
$blacklist = array("PCabc", "PCxyz");

foreach($blacklist as $blacklists){
              if (strpos($mail_body, $blacklists) !== false){


                echo "<br>".$mail_body."<br>";
              }
}
```

Turns out. This code is actually a working whitelist.^^

But I want the opposite but it would only output an object for each string within the array if I change `!== false` to `== false`. So if I got 5 items in `$blacklist` it would output 5 times the same for every object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `echo` out of the loop. For example:

```
$mail_body = "<table>.....</table>";
$blacklist = array("PCabc", "PCxyz");
$output = true;

foreach($blacklist as $blacklists){
    if (strpos($mail_body, $blacklists) !== false){
        $output = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($output) {
    echo "<br>".$mail_body."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `!== false` and add a `break`. No need to continue with iteration.

Answer (score 2):

A little workaround, come out of `foreach` LOOP, and set a flag for existence of balacklisted words.After that based on the value of `isBlackListed`, proceed

```
$mail_body = "<table>.....</table>";
$blacklist = array("PCabc", "PCxyz");

$isBlackListed = false;  //initialize to false

foreach($blacklist as $blacklists){
         if (strpos($mail_body, $blacklists) !== false){
              $isBlackListed = true;  
              //on encounter of blacklisted word , set this to true
        }
}

// proceed based on $isBlacklisted value

if( !$isBlackListed)
    echo "<br>".$mail_body."<br>";
```